# Cannot unmarshell intents on ICS

Tags: android, serialization, android-intent, marshalling, unmarshalling

I've a home screen implementation in which I store "shortcuts" by marshelling it using `Parcel` and storing it as Base32 string.

marshelling and unmarshelling works fine absolutely fine except for one scenario:

If I marshell the intent on Honeycomb (or lower) and try to unmarshell it on ICS (or higher), I get null pointer exception. (This is also true vice-versa, means marshelled on ICS and unmarshelled on HC also falis)

But marshelling - unmarshelling across Froyo, GB and HC works absolutely fine. Same between ICS and JellyBean.

I'm using apache commons library for Base32 conversion. (I've also tried Base64, but it does not work either). There is no problem in encoding and decoding string from Base32.

This is my code:

```
public static Intent getIntentFromBase32String(final String s)
{
    try
    {
        final Parcel p = Parcel.obtain();
        final byte[] array = new Base32(true).decode(s);
        p.unmarshall(array, 0, array.length);
        p.setDataPosition(0);
        final Intent intent = (Intent)p.readValue(Intent.class.getClassLoader());
        return intent;
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        Logger.logError(e);
    }
    return null;
}

public static String getBase32StringFromIntent(final Intent intent)
{
    try
    {
        final Parcel p = Parcel.obtain();
        p.writeValue(intent);
        final byte[] array = p.marshall();
        return new Base32(true).encodeToString(array);
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        Logger.logError(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException in com.myapp.myhome.loadShortcuts Message: null
    android.content.Intent.readFromParcel(Intent.java:6222)
    android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:6202)
    android.content.Intent.readFromParcel(Intent.java:6229)
    android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:6202)
    android.content.Intent$1.createFromParcel(Intent.java:6193)
    android.content.Intent$1.createFromParcel(Intent.java:6191)
    android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:1993)
    android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1855)
    com.myapp.common.utils.getIntentFromBase32String(Unknown Source)
    .....
```

I guess that Google added some extra attributes to Intent in ICS, due to which its serialized image is not compatible with older versions. Can there be a workaround for this?

Comment: have you found any solution?